# How can it be bigger on the inside

Tags: internal-consistency, physics, spacetime-dimensions, alien-geometry

We have these "magical" items everywhere in fiction; from the classic rabbit coming out of a hat illusion, to the TARDIS from *Doctor Who*, to Newest Magical Beast Newt Scamander Briefcase. These items all share same characteristic: a container with interior spaces that are much larger than they appear to be externally.

My question: Are there any possibilities of how this could be done based on science theorems and/or hypothesis?

To narrow things down I will set some rules:

1. A teleportation answer is not acceptable. The answer must take some form of a container, not Portal's hula-hoop like gate.
2. All item inside aren't just compressed, at least if we get inside we wouldn't feel that our body had been shrunk down.
3. Main question is about Volume differentiation. However you can try to answer the weight differentiation of the interior vs exterior, but its not necessary.

Bonus: If there exist possibilities, would there be some limit to the difference of the exterior volume vs the interior volume?

Can we put a portion of our universe with some galaxies inside a peanut size container?

Comment: Look at [how to fit monsters in your pocket](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/47251/whats-the-most-reasonable-way-to-fit-monsters-in-your-pocket)

Comment: @Kys I've seen it, that's why I add rules of no teleportation portal, and compression of matters. But if this question are still considered the same and by forum rules considered answered, please do tell me. I will close it.

Comment: See [this article](http://enthea.org/library/traversable-wormholes-some-implications/#10). Look also at the PDF magazine containing a later version.

Comment: In the end, it's all Timey Wimey Wibbely Wobbely stuff.It's all about phyiscs, physics, physics...

Comment: It's explained in one of the older Dr. Who TV shows.  Something along the lines of "Do you know how something very far away can be very big, but you can fit it between your fingers from a distance?  Well it's like that, just on the inside."

Comment: See [Eon by Greg Bear](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eon_%28novel%29). It's a futuristic pseudo-scientific approach to the problem.

Comment: For Dr. Who the answer is simple **Time** **A**nd **R**elative **D**imension In **S**pace.  The show cannon specifically states that multiple dimensions and connected together to form the inner space using Time Lord tech.  In theory in many thousand years we could probably also do.  The TARDIS can grab as many dimensions as it needs to hold everything.    Another thing to consider all matter in our universe is 99% free space, because atoms are 99% free space.  If the air space was removed/compressed you could almost become 2d.

Comment: two words:  Pocket Dimension.   Or, if you remember classic Looney Tunes, the "Portable Hole."

Comment: As far as Doctor Who is concerned, the inside of the TARDIS is actually **a lot** larger than the outside. There is one episode, I think with the 10th doctor, where you see a room with an **sun** inside the TARDIS. From the context it seems it's not a miniature sun, either.

Comment: @NZKshatriya The Portable Hole made actual holes in walls and floors. It was never used for "bigger on the inside" scenarios.

Comment: @cybernard The 99% free space is not air space. And removing it does not make anything any less 3-dimensional.

Comment: @Servaes  Correct not air space.  However if it were removed, or reduced to 1% we would be very thin.  We wouldn't be 2d, but maybe from a distance it would be hard to tell.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I have done some thinking about making an “abcess” or “bleb” of folded spacetime on the far side of a throat that’s smaller than the room it contains.

I’ll illustrate using flatland.  Draw a small circle. Inside that circle, push the flat sheet perpendicular to the plane, making a deep dent; continue stretching as if to make a wormhole. Then *inflate* the dead-end like blowing up a balloon.

The flatlanders outside the circle are not affected. Upon reaching the circle they find a tunnel to a room that’s “bigger on the inside”.

When I came up with this, I had been thinking that the throat could be shrunk to microscopic size and a submarine can be inside, providing miniaturization. Access to the outside world is through this throat, so I was speculating on how it would appear.

The “mass” is essentially screened, appearing (on the outside) as a constant mass of the wormhole stabilizing structure, or an apparent mass that being what would cause the same curvature of spacetime seen near the wormhole mouth.

That is, consider a normal wormhole, where you assume that the mouths can be moved independantly. If it’s the same for a wormhole leading to a pocket universe or a rented warehouse in this universe, moving the mouth does not make you drag around everything you have stored too.

So, I have a mechanism whose only purpose is to support the wormhole mouth and hold the door.  It might look like a prehung door for sale at the hardware store, or might need more support equipment so it's like a small phone booth.  You can move that around and it’s just the mass of the door and the mouth.  But if you go through the door the warehouse at the far end holds a huge amount of mass.

Now just having a wormhole to a warehouse elsewhere is too mundane.  Lead to a pocket universe, but keep the ability to move the two mouths independently and not pulling on the pocket universe space.

Comment: I remember a fictional gadget Doraemon's Gulliver's tunnel? The object that go through gate A to gate B is scaled down, while object that go through gate B to gate A is scaled up, and the scaling factor is the same for any object. Is the throat you mention work in a same way?

Comment: @HarizRizki no. I elaborated by post.  The Gulliver Tunnel doesn’t seem to explain anything though.

Comment: Oh I see now. I seem to anchored to 'miniaturization' before.

Comment: Your method also made it easier to imagine to create the space without the creator needed to be a higher dimensional being. I get it.

Comment: Yes, “it’s smaller on the outside!”  I was specifically looking at shilding real mass so you could have the [Fantastic Voyage](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0060397/) trope with hard science.

Comment: Well, how if you didn't need to do anything? since on the flatlanders model in your answer the circle properties and everything outside didn't affected. So to bring that up to a 3D model any properties of the exterior also didn't affected since the interior had expanded to stretch  and filled to another dimension. So you can extremely put a universe inside a purse while you feel it on outside that the purse is empty, is that plausible?

Comment: In a normal wormhole, you assume that the mouths can be moved independantly. If it's the same for a wormhole leading to a pocket universe or a rented warehouse in *this* universe, moving the mouth does not make you drag around everything you have stored too.

Answer (score 84):

In such matters, it's always helpful to scale things down to the familiar. So, imagine for a moment that you are a 2-dimensional being. You can move freely left or right, back or forward, but you have no conception at all of up or down. Then suppose that your house exists on a sheet of paper.

I, a three-dimensional being, can take that piece of paper and fold it several times. Each time its size halves, while at the same time having exactly the same surface area inside the folds.

By the time I've folded it several times, I can place it easily inside a small square in your 2-dimensional world. As long as I line up the entrances carefully, you can pass through a gap in the square and walk back and forth across the surface of the sheet of paper. Because it's folded through a dimension you have no access to, your perception is that the paper is bigger on the inside.

Comment: +1, this answer is very interesting! I just don't know if it solves the problem about the weight difference. Scamander's briefcase is not heavy but holds many heavy beasts. In your line of thought, the folded piece of paper would have the same weight of the unfolded paper, which is not the case.

Comment: I got some thinking that if you do it like this you will 'sacrifice' the upper dimension at least in that particular space. I mean If we are 2 dimensional being that can observe a 3 dimensional space (but we can't access them freely) then we can't observe them anymore  in a folded paper space, since the 3rd dimension there had been filled with a stack of folded 2 dimensional space). If we apply this same rule on 3 dimensional space then I think the 4th dimension (if we agree the 4th is time) in the container would also cease to exist, because we try to multiply the container volume.

Comment: And use the upper dimension (this case the 4th) to place them.  I think that  the container would have a unique 'trait' that when you put something inside the space the object will be available in that container in a state that time stop inside. So you can put a hamster and  pull it out hundred years later and the hamster just felt like it was an instant.

Comment: Time isn't "the" fourth dimension, it's a different *type* of dimension. Space dimensions and time dimensions work differently. If you folded three dimensional space through a time dimension, then you'd be able to travel in time by walking from one side of a room to the other. Instead, "Bigger on the inside" objects fold or offset space through a hidden fourth *spatial* dimension.

Comment: Ok, altough my mind still failed to think about it. So its like adding another axis in like 3D have 3 axis then,while time still didn't affected. Is there any reading that I can access regarding this type of fourth or more spatial dimensions?

Comment: That's essentially the same as mine, but I have smoother derivitives.  Seriously, you approach it as the folding is part of the embedding, while I look at the intrinsic topology with a mind toward making it a real possibility in GR.  My way (originally for miniaturization) deals with the weight.

Comment: @Zanon If you ever manage to solve that problem, I can show you a perceptual motion machine.

Comment: But how is the 2D being able of walking into the 3D room? The layer on top of it's current layer is not visible to it. For all it cares, everything above and beneath him is a different universe.

Comment: Because there's a 2D pathway that curves through 3D space. The 2D being doesn't even notice the curvature - as far as it's concerned, there's no folding, they're just following the path that's in front of them. They might notice some odd resistance here or there as they push against gravity from a source they can't even see, but they're still just following what they perceive to be a 2D path.

Comment: @Zanon the weight is in the 3 dimensional space, not in the two-dimensional. For a 2D creature, the folded paper does not weight more. A pan-dimensional object needs to be weighted in its top-most dimensional space.

Comment: @Werrf I actually do travel in time when walking from one side of a room to the other ;)

Comment: @Mindwin doesn't string theory theorize that gravity permeates through all spatial dimensions (which is why it's so weak compared to the other forces)?

Comment: @Griffin no. A space cannot perceive gravity that pulls in a dimension it has not. So a dual-dimensional space cannot know that a folder paper on top of it has weight going down, because it only understands north-south-east-west.

Comment: @Zanon It may be interesting to point out that Scamander's case is mainly powered by finely-grained unobtanium, e.g. "magic".

Answer (score 18):

D&D's Bag of holding (and other spells & effects) describe the use of [pocket dimensions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pocket_universe) to achieve this. Also see: Rope Trick. The bag does not compress or use a portal; the inside of the bag is an actual extradimensional and finite space with rigid boundaries. For the Bag of holding, these boundaries have some connection to the physical outside of the bag: If the bag is pierced, within or without, the bridge to the dimension disappears and you lose all your stuff forever.

Comment: Also [Flat Space technology from the Ultraviolet universe](http://moa.omnimulti.com/Flat-Space_technology)

Comment: The Tardis is said to use a similar trick of Trans-dimensional engineering.http://www.bbc.co.uk/programmes/profiles/5Dp7g7b0dSVhD2TM1xNlf7c/the-tardis

Comment: Mary Poppins.........original Bag of Holding....

Comment: Also note that placing a Bag of Holding inside another such bag causes bad things to happen.

Answer (score 6):

You can construct Einstein metrics which have the property of "Bigger on the Inside".  For example

$$ ds^2 = -c^2 dt^2 + a(r)^2 \left( dr^2+r^2 d\theta^2+r^2 sin^2 \theta 
 \, d\phi^2 \right)$$

with $a(r) =1 $ for   $r > R$ and $a \gg 1$ for, $r < R$.  If you calculate the volume inside a sphere of radius $R$ you will find a much greater volume than normal but a standard surface area.

You can calculate the Einstein tensor of this geometry to find the matter configuration needed to create this geometry (I believe it would violate certain energy conditions.)

Comment: Welcome to WorldBuilding *jman*! If you have a moment please take the [tour] and visit the [help] to learn more about the site. Have fun!

Answer (score 4):

Some theories about Space time I have heard imply that it can expand not only indefinitely (Big rip theory, which is that the universe never stops expanding), to being able to expand in such vast quantities that the spacetime between 2 objects, and hence the distance between them, can increase so that if both objects emmited light that went at C for eternity toward eachother, they would never meet (One of the theories about the Big Bang was that it became light years in diameter in at most a few seconds). It is common that Space time is not limited to things such as the speed of light, and even today we observe Redshift of galaxies that implies that light being sent from us now will never reach them because of the amount of space being created between us and them.

So what does all of this have to do with [Hammerspace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hammerspace) and the like? Its simple, Because space can theoretically expand like this, then the idea that we can selectively make it expand in a contained area is also not far fetched. There is no Teleportation or anything, Its just the physical space inside of a container has been forcefully expanded, and is contained in the container.

Of course, We are no where near technologically advanced enough to determine if this is actually possible, and what would actually happen to surrounding space time and the container if we tried, but so long as this is not a Hard Science universe, Hand wavium away.

Comment: I like how you based it in expandable universe theory. But I notice you need some 'ambiguity' to make it happen. Like dot A and dot B in a transparent bag C must be further apart when you see them with your face in the bag. While it not that apart when you see them from the outside. I imagine this kind of space is like a rearview mirror, nice.

Answer (score 2):

### The space is shrunk, but it doesn't seem like it.

Things in the container effectively are shrunk. But you don't feel shrinking nor does it look shrunk if you look inside. That's because everything *including your hands and even light* gets shrunk too. As the light exits the space, paths are bent in such a way that everything looks normally sized.

Answer (score 2):

## Take a page from String Theory

There are many flavours of String Theory. My favorite is called type IIB, for two reasons: it reminds me of a very lovely robot and it has a very creative quantum description of black holes.

In general relativity, a black hole is a body so dense that it has an event horizon: a region around it with an escape velocity greater than that of light. That necessitates a singularity at the center and creates more troubles for physics than it solves. You read enough about this, and you get ideas about wormholes, time travel and information paradoxes.

In IIB, a black hole is more properly described as a fuzzball. The whole of the black hole is its surface (the event horizon). There is no inside. [From PBS Spacetime](https://www.pbs.org/video/are-black-holes-actually-fuzzballs-qhoojx/) (one of my favorite shows) (also the emphasis below is mine):

> As a fuzzball is forming, all of the matter - now dissolved into stringy mess, is pushed up to the surface and **the interior grid of spacetime is deleted from the universe.**

Funny thing: the reason why the fuzzball has, externally, all the same properties as your regular black hole is that it behaves kinda like an interiorless katamari: everything that touches it becomes part of it, including light. Unlike a katamari, though, it won't break if you hit it with any force at all.

IIB also stipulates that the universe has 10 dimensions (or branes), with four being time and space, and the other six being really compacted. These dimensions can be distorted just like the strings in them, which is what allows for the fuzzball to be a region of space with no inside.

Just the same, it is very theoretically possible to poke a hole into a fuzzball and then refill the space inside it. And the space inside can then become arbitrarily large, not being bound by the outside in any manner. You can also loop the branes inside. You can have a separate, possibly infinite universe in there if you mess around enough.

Now, regardless of what is inside, the outside will only ever notice the mass of the fuzzball itself (without the contents of the branes you put in)! Just the same, those inside will not notice anything from the universe outside. The only interaction between the inside and outside is through the aperture through which you inserted the branes. Close the gap, and you have two parallel universes.

The only thing you need now to avoid killing everyone in a very messy manner is to put some surface over the fuzzball so that people don't touch it, because remember: you touch it, you become part of it FOREVER. No, really: every string that makes the particles in your body gets disassembled and is absorbed by the more complex strings forming the fuzzball. There is no going back.

So in order to make Newt's suitcase, for example:

1. Make a microscopic black hole. For comparison, a coin-sized one might be as massive as the Earth. We are really talking microscopic here so it weights no more than a suitcase.
2. Contain it somehow (static, maybe? Black holes can have electric charge). Make the container look like a suitcase.
3. Poke a hole on the fuzzball. This is the magic part of this, as even string theory offers little help here (even though it kinda implies it is possible).
4. Insert some branes (i.e.: spacetime and other dimensions) into the hole.
5. Stretch the aperture of the fuzzball to fit the open suitcase, and stretch the inside as well.
6. If you want the inside to have comfortable gravity, you can either make it spin (makes keeping the opening relatively static complex), or have a planet inside the fuzzball and build the "interior" of the suitcase on top of it.
7. ???
8. Profit!

Comment: "If you want to have comfortable gravity..." then you're out of luck. The curvature of space at the 'entrance' would produce more gravity than any of us are going to be comfortable with. Spaghettification comes to mind.

Answer (score 1):

A simple mathematical way to get around the problem is to use the concept of [diffeomorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffeomorphism?wprov=sfla1). According to this concept, if there are two different manifolds which are continuous and differentiable everywhere, one can map every point from manifold 1 to some point on manifold 2 or vice-versa. In other words, there is a one-to-one correspondence between them.

Now, for a three dimensional volume, it can get a bit tricky to do. But we can do it for sure. Consider an object which is solid and it can be cut off into many 2 dimensional manifolds by peeling it off. Take the outer most layer as a manifold and label it as $M_1^1$. Take a container whose volume is smaller than the solid object's volume and imagine an imaginary 3-d 'hollow' shape inside it. Now take the outermost layer of this 'hollow' shape and label it as manifold $M_2^1$. Now map each point of $M_1^1$ to each point of $M_2^1$ as $M_1^1 \rightarrow M_2^1$. Next take the next outermost layer from both solids as $M_1^2$ and $M_2^2$ respectively. Go on taking subsequent mappings as $M_1^i \rightarrow M_2^i$, (where $i$ is the ordinal number of the manifold taken, starting from the outermost and all the way to the central point) and you will have complete mappings from the points of solid object to the points of the 'hollow' object inside of the container and the solid object would fit inside the container even though the container's volume is smaller than solid's volume.